# Custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

I have made a custom post type called "Case Studies".

There is a case studies page which displays the title of every custom post and a small exceprt. However when you click on the title to view the single post, on the navigation the current tab changes from "`Case studies`" to "`News`". Where news is the default post page and case studies is a templated page.

Is there a way to make the custom post type a child of the `Case Studies` page? Or atleast set a template file that I can use for the custom post type. When you view a single `case study` post I need the navigation to show that you are still on the `Case Studies` page and not on News.

Thanks

Comment: how are the tabs activated at the moment? Using CSS? have you used firebug to see if you can tweak the rule to make it work for you?

Comment: it uses wordpress's .current-page class.I cant use jquery to remove class and add the class to the right menu item because I need full no-javascript compatability. ):

Comment: Can you add the code from the menu for case studies and the single custom post type?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Template redirect for custom templates
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect' );

public function template_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'case_studies' ) {
        get_template_part( 'single-casestudies' ); // a custom page-slug.php template
        die();
    }
}
```

This is the same thing that @Dalton mentioned, you would want to create a custom page template named page-casestudies.php or whatever you want to name it, then make a page in WP admin that has a slug of 'casestudies' to match the page-{slug}.php or page-{id}.php where the page id matches. And you can use the page.php code, with a line or two before the if(have_posts() while(have_posts() Loop. Sort of like this:

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'case_studies', 'paged' => $paged ));

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Sorry if I misunderstood the problem, but I think this would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use the rewrite parameter to change the permalink to your custom post type. As far as creating a custom post template, the format is single-CUSTOMPOSTTYPE.php

Here's the reference I found for this: http://kovshenin.com/archives/extending-custom-post-types-in-wordpress-3-0/

For example, on my site I have a normal page called "Animation" which is a landing page for my custom post type (animations). My rewrite slug is 'animation' and my template is single-animation.php. The permalink structure looks like mysite.com/animation/name-of-animation